# TrainingHelper in Tensorflow seq2seq don't use start token as the initial input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp

In my understand, the first input of the decoder for seq2seq model is the start token. But when I read the code from TrainingHelper in `tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py`, I found it just return the first token of the target tokens as the first token:

```
  def initialize(self, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name, "TrainingHelperInitialize"):
      finished = math_ops.equal(0, self._sequence_length)
      all_finished = math_ops.reduce_all(finished)
      next_inputs = control_flow_ops.cond(
          all_finished, lambda: self._zero_inputs,
          lambda: nest.map_structure(lambda inp: inp.read(0), self._input_tas))
      return (finished, next_inputs)
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to add start token by yourself before feed into TrainHelper

Answer (score 0):

Em... I have worked around nlp many times including seq2seq translation. But I have never heard about start token but only end token(`EOF`).

Although my seq2seq task worked well without anything like start token, I'm not sure if it is a new technique. If it is, thank you let me know.

Comment: I'm reading the code from [Google nmt](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt). The graph shows it feeds `<s>` as start token while decoding. But in the implement, it only uses the start token in infer part.

Comment: So without the start token, what's the initial input to the decoder RNN?

Comment: It can be just the first token of target tokens. After watching that article, I think start token is a good idea, it equals to the end token in output.

Comment: Oh, then it is the same with the implement of the TrainingHelper in TensorFlow. But there is no target tokens while infer, what do you use for the initial input?

Comment: Did you read  the whole article? https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#inference--how-to-generate-translations check this section.

Comment: Yes, I've read that. I was asking your method without start token before. I think it may be inspirational.

Comment: Actually, that is an old and outdated method. When training model, decoder use only the final output of encoder, that means encoder encode the whole sentence into a single vector, and then decoder use this single vector to decode. So the decoder doesn't need any other inputs both in training and predicting. The technique showing in the article seems to be a much better method.